# Bagged tree imputation method not working for big data?

Tags: r, missing-data, imputation

I have a huge data with 1000 variables and 200 subjects. Before starting to run the machine learning algorithm, I have to impute missing values. I use bagged tree imputation method. The problem is that whenever I impute missing values of 100 variables, the code works fine, but if I run it for 1000 variables, I get the `Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "NULL"` error. 
Here is a part of the code.

```
preProc <- preProcess(method="bagImpute", train[, 1:1000])
train[, 1:1000] <- predict(preProc, train[, 1:1000])
test[, 1:1000] <- predict(preProc, test[, 1:1000])
```

As it matters to me to use the same imputation method for both 100 and 1000 variables, I was wondering why the code does not work for 1000 variables.

Thanks in advance for your kind response.

Comment: Based on very high-level usage of bagImpute, I don’t think it can handle missing values for categorical variables. So, I suspect that your first 100 variables are all numeric, but beyond that do you have any categorical variables with missing values? If so, you would need to handle that first (replacing the missing categorical NAs) before using bagImpute.